# Is there a way to record internal audio?

Tags: audio-recording, amazon-kindle

I have Amazon Kindle (I don't have a USB cable, so I can't root the Kindle). I also have online lectures. For some reasons, my Kindle can stream faster than on my PC.

Now, I want to record the audio from online lectures directly from my Kindle so that I can listen to it while offline.

Most of the Android applications I've found record phone calls, which is not what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Samsung or LG phone, [Mobizen Screen Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rsupport.mobizen.sec) can capture internal audio.  I've tested on a Samsung but not LG.

Answer (score 0):

Install [Tape-a-Talk Voice Recorder](https://market.android.com/details?id=name.markus.droesser.tapeatalk). It can record even if you push it to background. If your Kindle doesn't have Android Market installed, try [this link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005S43E2E).

Answer (score 0):

There is no support in Android for doing what you want. You would need [kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14055272/android-4-0-ideas-how-to-record-capture-internal-audio-e-g-stream-music) or OS patching of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to record your android's internal audio without so much loss in quality right.

You can use a 3.5mm male to male cable and connect the other side of the cable in the Line in port (which is often marked as the blue 3.5mm port).

This way you can stream the audio/video on your phone and record it with a recording software like audacity on your PC.

This is not the original audio. This involves converting the digital to analog and back to digital again.

If you can't, for some reason stream near your PC you can make a custom TRRS jack which will feed the audio output back to your mic pin and record it with your phone. <s>I'm not entirely confident this will work.</s> I've tested it and it worked.

Comment: OP: "... *directly from my Kindle* "

Comment: Then the custom cable idea is worth giving a shot. 

in this article, they are talking about a TRRS to RCA cable and using it to record external audio. 
http://www.techradar.com/news/phone-and-communications/mobile-phones/add-an-audio-input-to-android-1189160

So theoretically, you can use the cable to feed your phone audio back to itself and record it.

Challenges:
1. It may not work due to impedance. Although they've managed it.
2. You have to find an audio recorder which doesn't stop lecture streaming during recording.