# How can I record audio running through my S3 speaker on Jellybean?

Tags: audio, audio-recording

On my computer I use Replay Media Catcher to capture audio or video clips I want to save offline from the web. Now on my Samsung Galaxy  S3 running 4.1.1 I want to record audio from websites. All I see on Play is "voice recoders" but I want a simple way to record audio coming from online to my phone as an .mp3 file etc. Any way?

What I want is to be able to record ANY audio running through my speaker not just from online.  Like, if I'm an audiobook on my audiobook app I want to record the sound coming from that.

Comment: Possibly relevant: [Is there a way to record sound coming from the speakers, like Audacity does on the computer?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20230/is-there-a-way-to-record-sound-coming-from-the-speakers-like-audacity-does-on-t)

Comment: I already read that.  It isn't what I'm looking for...

Comment: You may want to clarify your title (possibly the body as well) a little bit then, because it seems to be quite identical based on the current phrasing. The OP of that question was looking to record audio being played back from a website as well.

Comment: Can you help me edit it?  It's like I'm dumb or something.  That post talks about an app that doesn't have any internet-recording features.