# How to record a game music in Android?

Tags: audio, audio-recording

I failed to find the background soundtracks for some Android games, so I thought I could just record their music when the game is active but I don't seem to have any solution to do so.

I first thought of using some Android apps but all I see in Play Store and forums are links to apps recording voice of the user or the external environment (using mic) while I'm interested in audio I hear from speaker or earphones.

I also came to know of screen recorders but my default screen recorder records sound using mic and using screen recorder is an overkill since it tends to use a lot of CPU which is needed for the game. But I'm open for any suggestion.

Then I thought to find a file or something under Android which may be redirecting output to earphones or speaker or may be grab that final end and save it using ADB, but I seem to have no idea how to do that.

*I would like to draw attention specifically to the said ADB part i.e. anything related to Android that could solve the problem since the other parts or even the title might be considered off-topic for being Android Independent.*

So, how exactly do I record my favorite game's music?

Note that the question can be extended to any app, be it a media streaming or lecture app, or anything that plays sound and user wants to record it.

I'm using OnePlus One running CM12 and is rooted.

Comment: If you have a computer and Bluestacks then it will be easy to record the sounds since recording sounds in a computer is much easier than in mobile. I'll keep posted if I find anything mobile specific too ;)

Comment: Arch, if you could be more specific on what game/app sound you are trying to record you'll get more response.

Comment: @Lucky [Valiant Hearts: The Great War](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ubisoft.adventure.valiant_hearts), [The Bard's Tale](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.inxile.BardTale).

Comment: Both the games would have downloaded extra game data. Look for where the game data is downloaded. Most probably it will be in you `Internal memory-> Android -> data` directory. Look for mp3/wav files inside the corresponding packages of the games. Use FXexplorer app and search for sound file. It will be under some directory like assest or sounds directory etc.

Comment: @Lucky I already tried such things before posting this question. The pure extensions are not used be Games anymore, instead, developers uses their in-house proprietary extensions. But thanks for the info. :-)

Comment: Possibly related, but the existing answer seems not correct: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20230/is-there-a-way-to-record-internal-audio