# How can I record sound before outputting?

Tags: audio-recording

I have some apps that I want to record the output sounds locally before outputting to speaker, Bluetooth or any other output.
So I get clean unadulterated audio, before any audio output mods.

My devices are rooted, some have custom ROMs.

Is there a way to do this internally, without any programming/coding knowledge? Can this be accomplished? Preferably with out hooking to PC as that prevents local saving.

- include steps.
- include references

---

Please excuse lack of tags, limited on choices.

Comment: Probably related, but not sure if the existing answer is correct: [Is there a way to record internal audio?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/20230/44325). Meanwhile, I think I found another way using [SCR Screen Recorder](http://www.scr-screen-recorder.com/), but I haven't tested it. Also might be useful: [SCR Screen Recorder on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2422061) and [Recording internal audio on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/app-internal-audio-recording-t2948339) (warning: bad formatting)

Comment: @AndrewT. Even though the first link has an answer, that isn't exactly a complete answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SCR Screen Recorder](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/app-4-0-root-scr-screen-recorder.2422061/) is a screen(+audio) recorder app.

**Note: root access is needed for internal audio recording.** Also, the internal audio recording was said to be an experimental feature, which might not work on all devices.

1. Download and install **SCR Screen Recorder Pro v1.0.5** (not SCR 5+ Pro v0.1.3, which doesn't need root, but only works on Lollipop and doesn't support internal audio recording)
2. Open the app, it will display overlay buttons on the screen.
3. Open the SCR Settings (middle icon, the one with cog icon)
4. On the "Audio" header, tap **Source** and select **Internal**

   - Optional: if screen recording is not needed, it's recommended to select the lowest setting on the "Video" header to decrease the file size. (e.g. 426x240 resolution)
5. Open the target app to be recorded
6. **Adjust the volume from the Android device** (important!).

   - Note: since SCR uses the same audio stream as the source, the volume when the app plays the audio is used as the input. This means that if the audio is not recorded with 100% volume (e.g. 70%), the loudness of the audio will decrease when it's played back (i.e. similar to playing the "recorded audio on 70% volume" with 70% volume, thus the final output is more-or-less 50% volume compared to the original audio)
   - Ideally, if there is an external speaker, it's possible to set the volume to 100% in Android and adjust the volume to a comfortable zone on the external speaker.
   - Optional: turn off any notification on all apps to prevent noise.
7. When ready, tap the **Record** button (first icon with orange color)
8. To stop the recording, either:

   - open the app once again (from notification or app launcher), or
   - turn off the screen for 2 seconds

---

**Addendum by anonymous user**:

With root: when the settings have been configured to use internal audio and the notification icon is popped up, tap the home button (don't close SCR) and open any sound recorder. It will record the sound internally instead of with a mic. (tried with a 3rd-party HI-Q MP3 recorder, unsure about others..)

Comment: Great write up! I did a lot of research for recording internal audio only (about a years worth of scouring and reading). I didn't find anything, either. I'm going to the SCR app. I am also going to see if I can "sweet talk" the developor into releasing an audio only version (fingers-crossed). Thanks again @Andrew T.

Comment: @Andrew T. Upvoted . Thanks. You may like to post this or updated answer which can retain amr format to my [question](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/34185/20166) .  Will be happy to accept your answer there even if it can't record in amr format... The next time i visit